# No eyes in xeyes over ssh

Tags: x11, xforwarding

I have two devices — one a Mid-2009 MacBook, the other a 2008-2009 HP Pavilion — each running Fedora 29. The HP will eventually become headless, but for now, both machines are running KDE.

I can `ssh -X` into the HP and start applications. The first was `xeyes`, and strangely, it started, but did not have the iris dots that track the mouse. Next, I started Dolphin File Manager, which also started without file icons.

The solution to the Dolphin problem was entering 
`export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=kde`
which seemed strange since both computers are running the same version of KDE, but whatever.

I started xeyes again, and again, no dots.

More data:

`xfd -fn fixed`
worked just fine.

`xload -highlight blue`
didn't work at all.

Comment: Does your Fedora KDE have anything like "-nolisten tcp" in the xserverrc file when Xorg starts?

Comment: After trying this on a different monitor, I see that the xeyes pupils are just very faint grey, not missing.